# Ubuntu 22.04 and Firefox don't work with proxychains

Tags: networking, firefox, 22.04, proxy

I want to use Firefox and remmina via proxychains.
I have installed the app with `sudo apt get proxychains4`
When I enter `proxychains firefox` or `proxychains4 firefox` Firefox  uses the IP from the system and not the proxy-IP-address. The TOR-Service is running!
I have following configuration `/etc/proxychains4.conf`:

```
# proxychains.conf  VER 4.x
#
#        HTTP, SOCKS4a, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.


# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted
#
#dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
strict_chain
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#round_robin_chain
#
# Round Robin - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# of chain_len length
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped).
# the start of the current proxy chain is the proxy after the last
# proxy in the previously invoked proxy chain.
# if the end of the proxy chain is reached while looking for proxies
# start at the beginning again.
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
# These semantics are not guaranteed in a multithreaded environment.
#
#random_chain
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

# Make sense only if random_chain or round_robin_chain
#chain_len = 2

# Quiet mode (no output from library)
#quiet_mode

## Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
# (disable all of the 3 items below to not proxy your DNS requests)

# method 1. this uses the proxychains4 style method to do remote dns:
# a thread is spawned that serves DNS requests and hands down an ip
# assigned from an internal list (via remote_dns_subnet).
# this is the easiest (setup-wise) and fastest method, however on
# systems with buggy libcs and very complex software like webbrowsers
# this might not work and/or cause crashes.
proxy_dns

# method 2. use the old proxyresolv script to proxy DNS requests
# in proxychains 3.1 style. requires `proxyresolv` in $PATH
# plus a dynamically linked `dig` binary.
# this is a lot slower than `proxy_dns`, doesn't support .onion URLs,
# but might be more compatible with complex software like webbrowsers.
#proxy_dns_old

# method 3. use proxychains4-daemon process to serve remote DNS requests.
# this is similar to the threaded `proxy_dns` method, however it requires
# that proxychains4-daemon is already running on the specified address.
# on the plus side it doesn't do malloc/threads so it should be quite
# compatible with complex, async-unsafe software.
# note that if you don't start proxychains4-daemon before using this,
# the process will simply hang.
#proxy_dns_daemon 127.0.0.1:1053

# set the class A subnet number to use for the internal remote DNS mapping
# we use the reserved 224.x.x.x range by default,
# if the proxified app does a DNS request, we will return an IP from that range.
# on further accesses to this ip we will send the saved DNS name to the proxy.
# in case some control-freak app checks the returned ip, and denies to 
# connect, you can use another subnet, e.g. 10.x.x.x or 127.x.x.x.
# of course you should make sure that the proxified app does not need
# *real* access to this subnet. 
# i.e. dont use the same subnet then in the localnet section
#remote_dns_subnet 127 
#remote_dns_subnet 10
remote_dns_subnet 224

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

### Examples for localnet exclusion
## localnet ranges will *not* use a proxy to connect.
## note that localnet works only when plain IP addresses are passed to the app,
## the hostname resolves via /etc/hosts, or proxy_dns is disabled or proxy_dns_old used.

## Exclude connections to 192.168.1.0/24 with port 80
# localnet 192.168.1.0:80/255.255.255.0

## Exclude connections to 192.168.100.0/24
# localnet 192.168.100.0/255.255.255.0

## Exclude connections to ANYwhere with port 80
# localnet 0.0.0.0:80/0.0.0.0
# localnet [::]:80/0

## RFC6890 Loopback address range
## if you enable this, you have to make sure remote_dns_subnet is not 127
## you'll need to enable it if you want to use an application that 
## connects to localhost.
# localnet 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
# localnet ::1/128

## RFC1918 Private Address Ranges
# localnet 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
# localnet 172.16.0.0/255.240.0.0
# localnet 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0

### Examples for dnat
## Trying to proxy connections to destinations which are dnatted,
## will result in proxying connections to the new given destinations.
## Whenever I connect to 1.1.1.1 on port 1234 actually connect to 1.1.1.2 on port 443
# dnat 1.1.1.1:1234  1.1.1.2:443

## Whenever I connect to 1.1.1.1 on port 443 actually connect to 1.1.1.2 on port 443
## (no need to write :443 again)
# dnat 1.1.1.2:443  1.1.1.2

## No matter what port I connect to on 1.1.1.1 port actually connect to 1.1.1.2 on port 443
# dnat 1.1.1.1  1.1.1.2:443

## Always, instead of connecting to 1.1.1.1, connect to 1.1.1.2
# dnat 1.1.1.1  1.1.1.2

# ProxyList format
#       type  ip  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#       only numeric ipv4 addresses are valid
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#               socks5  192.168.67.78   1080    lamer   secret
#       http    192.168.89.3    8080    justu   hidden
#       socks4  192.168.1.49    1080
#           http    192.168.39.93   8080    
#       
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5, raw
#         * raw: The traffic is simply forwarded to the proxy without modification.
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )
#
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks4  127.0.0.1 9050
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `socks4` to `socks5` in the config file since the default port for tor is `socks5` port `9050`.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox over proxychains bypass proxy and reach the internet directly.
and torbrowser's socks5 port is "9150"